# php include - how to make variables available where included?

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping

I am trying to include a file which is scraping all my data from varrious  websites, however its not working. Heres my code.

firstly, the scraping php file. named scrapedata.php

```
<?php

//Include the Simple HTML DOM to use its functions, used by other following scripts.
//navigate to the content of variable html and save it in price data variable
//get the whole html of the webpage into variable html
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.play.com/Electronics/Electronics/4-/16230382/New-Apple-iPod-Touch-8GB-4th-Gen/Product.html?');
$price_data = $html->find('h6[id=bodycontent_0_middlecontent_1_ctl00_ctl00_product_ctl00__overview_ctl00__dataControl__price__headerSix',0)->plaintext; 


//Amazon.co.uk scrape
$amazon_html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Apple-iPod-touch-Generation/dp/B0040GIZTI/ref=br_lf_m_1000333483_1_1_img?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&pf_rd_p=229345967&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_t=1401&pf_rd_i=1000333483&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1ZW9HJW2KN2C2MTRJH60');
$amazon_pd = $amazon_html->find('b[class=priceLarge]',0)->innertext;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($amazon_html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expr = "/html/body/div[@id='divsinglecolumnminwidth']/form[@id='handleBuy']/table[3]/tr[3]/td/div/span";
$nodes = $xpath->query($expr); // returns DOMNodeList object
// you can check length property i.e. $nodes->length

//echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; // get first DOMNode object and its value
$stock_data = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

if ( $stock_data == "In stock." ) {
    $stockyesno = "Yes";
} else {
    $stockyesno = "No";
}

//Currys scrape
$currys_html = file_get_html('http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/apple-new-ipod-touch-8gb-4th-generation-07677427-pdt.html');
$currys_pd = $currys_html->find('p[class=prd-amount]',0)->plaintext;
$currys_stk = $currys_html->find('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li/span')->plaintext;
//span[class=icon icon-check]',0);

echo $currys_stk;

if ( $currys_stk == "Available for home delivery" ) {
    $currys_stockyesno = "Yes";
} else {
    $currys_stockyesno = "No";
}

//Argos scrape
$argos_html = file_get_html('http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/9282197/Trail/searchtext%3EIPOD+TOUCH.htm');
$argos_pd = $argos_html->find('span[class=actualprice]',0)->plaintext; 

//Ebuyer scrape
$ebuyer_html = file_get_html('http://www.ebuyer.com/product/237805');
$ebuyer_pd = $ebuyer_html->find('span[class=now]',0)->plaintext;

//PcWorld scrape
$pcworld_html = file_get_html('http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/apple-new-ipod-touch-8gb-4th-generation-07677427-pdt.html');
$pcworld_pd = $pcworld_html->find('p[class=prd-amount]',0)->plaintext; 
?>
```

and then my page where its included, to then which its meant to access the data in the variables from the included file.

```
<?php include 'scrapedata.php';?>     


   <!-- MYSQL DATABASE CODE -->
  <?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'admin';
$db_pwd = '1admin';

$database = 'stock_checker';
$table = 'price_stock';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

?> 
<!-- MYSQL DATABASE CODE END-->
```

```
  //Insert the scraped data into the database.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_stock (retailer,price) VALUES('Play.com', '$play_pd' )") 
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_stock (retailer,price,stock) VALUES('Amazon', '$amazon_pd', '$stockyesno' )") 
or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_stock (retailer,price,stock) VALUES('Currys', '$currys_pd', '$currys_stk' )") 
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_stock (retailer,price) VALUES('Argos', '$argos_pd' )") 
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_stock (retailer,price) VALUES('eBuyer', '$ebuyer_pd' )") 
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO price_stock (retailer,price) VALUES('PCWorld', '$pcworld_pd' )") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

?>

```
<!-- MYSQL DATABASE % TABLE CREATION CODE -->
<?php
// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);


echo "<table width='650px'><tr>";

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);


?>
```

Have I done this correctly ? I don't know if they would automattically be included, or they have to be made GLOBAL ?

Comment: Apologies all, I somehow forgot to include the code where I insert data into the database. doh!, its there now!

Comment: So the included file runs, it gives no error, and the data doesn't appear.

Is the scraped data being written to the database? When you check the DB what's in there?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea.

You should be using functions; passing and returning values. Include files at the beginning of the script, call functions when needed. Do not put any freestanding (non-function) code in files you include.

(By the way, the next step is OOP and autoloaders.)

And in case you're wondering why this is a very bad idea: I've looked over your code 5 times now (though with no in-depth analysis) and *still* haven't figured out what variables you want to share between the two files. If I went line-by-line, I'd find it, but I don't want to go line-by-line. Neither do you, in 3 months, when you're updating the code. Make our job easier.

--

From a point of view, an object is a collection of functions and the state they share; so it's the third step here: no functions -> some functions -> functions grouped together in classes. Don't even know if it's any good, but PHP has [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) to say about OOP. [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is the mechanism PHP uses to load classes on-demand, usually saving you from includes.

Comment: I had made a mistake and forgot to include the mysql insert code, thats where the variables are that link up with the included file. I also moved the include scrapedata.php inside the mysql code script.

I understand, it is probably a very bad idea, but this is for a uni project, and I have come from no knowledge of php or mysql, this is just from what I picked up and put together, I had no knoweldge of what was good or not, or what one would generally use to accomplish something.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain autoloaders and OOP? , I'm going to need to research, I have no idea :(

Comment: Im not sure if it helps, but the reason I am making in an external file to which its then included, is because I need to run it using a cron job every 5 minutes. Then the new data can be overwritten the old records.

Answer (score 0):

They don't need to be imported explicitly.

Try this example:

```
<?php
// a.php
$myVar = 123;
```

and

```
<?php
// b.php
include 'a.php'
echo isset($myVar)?'Included':'Not included';
```

Related to your posted code: I don't see where you add data to the database. Shouldn't you do that as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use DOM Parsing for such requests. Amazon released a simple API - read here: http://aws.amazon.com/de/

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables in the included file will appear in the main file by the same name.

But in your code I don't see variables being reused at all? The scrape generates information in variables, then your main file reads an unrelated database table. The two operations need to relate somehow.

Comment: Apologies, I somehow forgot to inlucde the mysql code which calls the variables from the external php file.