# PHP passing variables via include files (relative path vs absolute path)

Tags: php, variables, include, scope, filepath

I want to pass a variable defined in an include file, *identity.php*, to the parent file, which I'll call *parent.php*. When I include identity.php via it's relative path, the variable is available to the *parent.php* file. When I include *identity.php* via it's absolute path (to the application root), it doesn't work. Why is this?

*File: identity.php*

```
$g_groupid = 2;
```

*File: parent.php*

```
include('absolute_path_to_identity.php');
echo $g_groupid; //NOTHING!
```

However...
*File: parent.php*

```
include('../../identity.php'); //relative path to include file 
echo $g_groupid; //echos 2 as expected
```

I have verified that identity.php is **included in both cases** by echoing a "identity file is included message" (from within the *identity.php* file) which is displayed for both the relative and absolute includes. What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Enable full error reporting. Most likely the absolute path you used is wrong.

Comment: I have echoed the absolute path and it is correct. I have also included an echo statement within the include file and the message is echoed in both cases - indicating the file has been included for both instances.

Comment: File is not included for sure. you should use `require` instead of `include` to confirm

Comment: @ShaktiSingh File is included. I experience the same issue when using require instead. I will be going ahead with the relative include - coz it works! - but it'll be useful to know why it doesn't work in the later case.

Comment: [Globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). The design should be changed to [encapsulate the code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5646594/) in functions & classes, making this issue moot.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your "absolute path" is an URL like `http://www.example.com/folder/identity.php`
If that's the case PHP will fetch the code from the web server using HTTP, and so all PHP code will be evaluated *before* the file is included.

This will give the behavior you described with the `echo` troubleshooting as well.

An "absolute path" is on the form `/home/user/public_html/folder/identity.php` and is not the same thing as an URL.

---

Consider this:

**identity.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Is included';
$g_groupid = 2;
?>
```

When evaluated by the PHP interpreter this will result in this raw text:

```
Is included
```

If you include *that raw text* into **parent.php** it will behave as if it was raw HTML without any PHP code because there are no `<?php` tags in that raw text. Then consider this **identity.php**:

```
<?php
echo 'Is included <?php $g_groupid = 3; ?>';
$g_groupid = 2;
?>
```

Which will result in this:

```
Is included <?php $g_groupid = 3; ?>
```

What results do you get in your **parent.php** now? Is $g_groupid `2` or `3`?

Comment: Including a file using an absolute path is not like including it as a raw text. You are not "Reading" the file , you are including it (meaning its processed by php), so its irrelevant.

Comment: Did you try adding error reporting like i wrote in my answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [realpath()](http://us.php.net/realpath) ?

```php
require_once(realpath('../../identity.php'));
```

Also, I recommend turning off error reporting if its not on already so you can make sure the file is indeed included, and get some more info on this. Add this on the top of your file :

```php
ini_set("display_errors","On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your absolute path is working?

I had similar issues and I use, in this case, always the full path through DOCUMENT_ROOT

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_file_path.php");
```

Answer (score -3):

Hmm, try:

```
include('absolute_path_to_identity.php');
global $g_groupid;
echo $g_groupid;
```

Comment: I think the global will only be required if we want to access the variable from within a function, no?

Comment: Yes, I know. Bu this is a non usual bug, I've think it helps. I am wrong